# Equivalent of "curl -F" parameter for System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent?

Tags: c#, curl, multipartform-data, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to use the [sonicAPI file/upload API](https://www.sonicapi.com/docs/api/file-upload) in C#.

My attempt to translate the curl example to C# with `HttpClient` and `MultipartFormDataContent` returns the error *400 / Bad Request*.

Content of the response :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
   <status code="400" />
   <errors>
      <error message="File upload failed: file is missing." parameter="file" error_code="10" />
   </errors>
</response>
```

Example of the curl command-line shown in the documentation :

`curl https://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id=$ACCESS_ID -Ffile=@Vocals.mp3`

Code I've crafted so far :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string id, string fileName)
{
    string url = string.Format("http://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id={0}", id);
    var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);

    var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) };
    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file");

    HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    string s = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return message;
}
```

I've tried to remove `"file"` from `content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file");` but it didn't help.

Note : the upload happens (i.e. it does not return immediately)

Do you know what is the equivalent of the curl -F parameter when using .NET web classes ?

EDIT :

Output of curl -v

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 87.106.252.119...
* Connected to api.sonicapi.com (87.106.252.119) port 80 (#0)
> POST /file/upload?access_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: api.sonicapi.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 882266
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------b3c6dc0fc9
34fc71
>
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
* Server nginx/0.7.67 is not blacklisted
< Server: nginx/0.7.67
< Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 21:14:09 GMT
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Express
< X-Sonicapi-Request-Id: 6422cd9a-6069-4c2f-a3c5-0865c8ada6d5
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< location: /file/download?file_id=dae4e051-fe11-4058-a009-855dbb74de50
< X-Sonicapi-File-Id: dae4e051-fe11-4058-a009-855dbb74de50
< Content-Length: 249
<
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><response><status code="201"/><file file_i
d="dae4e051-fe11-4058-a009-855dbb74de50" status="ready" href="/file/download?fil
e_id=dae4e051-fe11-4058-a009-855dbb74de50" remaining_lifetime_seconds="3599"/></
response>* Connection #0 to host api.sonicapi.com left intact
```

Output of the request using Fiddly :

```
POST http://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id=xxxxxxxx
HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="bd6fba7f-c173-4470-9c44-c9cc91f618a9"
Host: api.sonicapi.com
Content-Length: 882175
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--bd6fba7f-c173-4470-9c44-c9cc91f618a9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file

RIFFvu
�WAVEfmt
```

(truncated)

Comment: If you look at (and/or show us) the HTTP request generated by curl (using Fiddler, for example) and compare it to the HTTP request generated by your code, it might provide some insight.

Comment: I've added both outputs, unfortunately I can't get the output of curl running in cmd with Fiddly, nothing is intercepted.

Comment: You have to [manually tell curl to use a proxy (i.e. "Fiddly")](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2007-03/0032.html). Also, what's the second HTTP request? It just says "the request" in your question, and it looks radically different from your other HTTP request (that says "curl -v"). Also, is your `curl -v` actually `curl -v -F ...`?

Comment: I got it ! Did a small progress but was still getting 400, last hope was to set stream content header instead of multipart form data content and it's working now :D thank you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @bzlm, using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) I managed to track what was missing :

- Content disposition
- Content type

And these needed to be set on `streamContent` rather than `content`.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(string id, string fileName)
{
    string url = string.Format("http://api.sonicapi.com/file/upload?access_id={0}", id);
    var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
    string name = Path.GetFileName(fileName);

    var client = new HttpClient { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10) };

    var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data");
    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name = "\"file\"";
    streamContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "\"" + name + "\"";
    streamContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    var content = new MultipartFormDataContent { streamContent };
    HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
    string s = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return message;
}
```

Comment: While you're waiting, you could make a Sonic C# Helper Library so that others can use C# easily to use the Sonic API, without needing to fiddle about as you had to. You already have one helper method finished. :)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing ! I spent the whole day on it and I'm almost finished :D I'll probably put it on NuGet and/or on their site . Actually I've just asked another question about a problem I'm having with it if you can shed some light on it that'd be great : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890513/no-freezes-alternative-to-thread-sleep-for-waiting-inside-a-task Thank you.

Comment: Wow, great! If you put it on Github instead, others can help you build it.

Comment: Oh yes and in GitHub of course ! that's what I did already for this audio-related library : https://www.nuget.org/packages/ENMFPdotNet/ and https://github.com/aybe/ENMFPdotNet

Comment: @bzlm Hi, I've finally create a package for it ! https://www.nuget.org/packages/SonicApi/

Comment: Wow, impressive! Starred you on GitHub. :)

Comment: Cool, they're going to use it as the official API.