# No-freezes alternative to Thread.Sleep for waiting inside a Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, wait

I have to call a web API that works as follows :

1. upload a song
2. request a particular analysis on that song
3. **wait** that the process is finished
4. retrieve and return the result

I am having a problem with no. 3, I've tried `Thread.Sleep` but that freezes the UI.

How can I wait in a task without freezing the UI ?

```
public override async Task Execute(Progress<double> progress, string id)
{
    FileResponse upload = await Queries.FileUpload(id, FileName, progress);
    upload.ThrowIfUnsucessful();

    FileResponse analyze = await Queries.AnalyzeTempo(id, upload);
    analyze.ThrowIfUnsucessful();

    FileResponse status;
    do
    {
        status = await Queries.FileStatus(id, analyze);
        status.ThrowIfUnsucessful();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    } while (status.File.Status != "ready");

    AnalyzeTempoResponse response = await Queries.FileDownload<AnalyzeTempoResponse>(id, status);
    response.ThrowIfUnsucessful();

    Action(response);
}
```

EDIT : this is how I call the task

```
async void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = @"d:\DJ SRS-Say You Never Let Me Go.mp3";
    TempoAnalyzeTask task = new TempoAnalyzeTask(fileName, target);
    await task.Execute(new Progress<double>(ProgressHandler), Id);
}
private AnalyzeTempoResponse _response;

private void target(AnalyzeTempoResponse obj)
{
    _response = obj;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to figure out how I can translate the link you've sent to `Task` instead of `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: @bzlm I agree but it would be better to point it at one of the many duplicates that show how to use `await Task.Delay(x)` instead in one of the answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For minimal changes just switch to [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `await` the result. This no longer blocks your UI while you wait 10 seconds just like your other three `await`s

```
FileResponse status;
do
{
    status = await Queries.FileStatus(id, analyze);
    status.ThrowIfUnsucessful();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
} while (status.File.Status != "ready");
```

Comment: Exactly that, thank you !

Comment: Best example I've seen for a do/while.