# cURL and .Net (c#) API Token (Token is Invalid)

Tags: c#, .net, api, curl

I've searched all over the internet and stackoverflow...can't really figure out if it's a code problem or the API is not valid anymore with some tokens...
I've looked through this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066674/curl-and-net-c-api-token) and tried it out and nothing. The only thing that returns is "TOKEN is invalid".

I'm trying to list the users from this event which has an API [here](https://codebits.eu/s/api).

This is my code:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://services.sapo.pt/Codebits/user/1/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("&token=NTUyI0FmY29zdGEjYW5kcmVjb3N0NEBnbWFpbC5jb20jZDkwMDdhNWUxOTNiN2VhMzcwMWJjNjI3MjMwMmI2YTQjMTQzMjU2NDU1NSNhMTc3YTdkZjNlYzk2MTg3ZjZmNzk1NTc3YjEwMDExOTcwNDE1ZTZj").Result;

        HttpContent responseContent = response.Content;

        //    //// Get the stream of the content.
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(await responseContent.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
        {

            //    //    return (await reader.ReadToEndAsync());

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                tb1.Text = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                tb1.Text = "x";
            }
        }
```

Since i'm kinda noob, I hope and think it is my problem but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What part of "TOKEN is invalid" is unclear?

Their [API help page mentions](https://codebits.eu/s/api):

> AUTHENTICATION AND USERS
>
> AUTH TOKEN
>
> https://services.sapo.pt/Codebits/gettoken?user=wookiee@sapo.pt&password=grumph
> Get the auth token. Will be used as a &token= argument with all the methods that require authentication. Please be aware that tokens may expire (due to timeout, IP change or others). The correct procedure for an app is to ask for a new token if the one it has fails in any of the methods that require authentication.

So when a call fails with "TOKEN is invalid", first make a `gettoken` call to obtain a valid token.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help! I forgot to say that I've already tried that, and still nothing :/